# How to show JApplet in a JSP page

Tags: eclipse, jsp, japplet

I am using:

1. Eclipse for Java EE developers
2. JSP
3. JDK1.8.0
4. Dynamic Web Project

I want to show an applet in my jsp page, but I am unsuccessful.

The issue is: when I run the page index.jsp page it shows an empty box in the browser having a little icon on top-left corner.

The screen shot of the whole scene is provided below:

[The overview of the scene can be seen in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpQKK.png)

Running it directly from Eclipse shows:

[Running directly with eclipse shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpPAi.png)

If we run the index.jsp page with this coding:

```
<jsp:plugin type="applet" code="gui.MainFrame.class" codebase="gui" width = "400" height = "400">
</jsp:plugin>
```

Output: only shows an empty box having a little icon on the top-left corner with the size 400 width and 400 height.

Please guide me, I am stuck on it. This is my final year's project.
Thanks.

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `WEB-INF` aren't served to browsers, including the `WEB-INF/classes` folder where all of this project's Java sources are compiled and deployed to on the server. You'll have to have its compiled class files in `WebContent` but outside of `WEB-INF`.

My suggestion would be to try creating a second Java source folder and explicitly setting its output folder to be somewhere in `WebContent` but outside of `WEB-INF`. It would then not require any work on the `Deployment Assembly` property page for the project because that page only affects server-side deployment--everything else under `WebContent`, including the applet class files, should just copy over.

Edit: It'll look like this, and you *must* have the option to set output folders for each source folder enabled:
[image: Allow output folders to be set for each source folder, then create one for the Applet sources and have it build into somewhere else under WebContent]

Comment: Would you please do a simple one applet dynamic web project and send it to me? My email: sikandarali744@gmail.com

I will be thankful to you. _thanks_ **Nitind**

Comment: Edited the answer so it's more reusable.

Comment: I tried it, but still the output is empy box.. Dear **Nitind** I am also confused in jsp:plugin code attribute and codebase attribute.

Comment: Those two things I'm not an expert on. Time to make use of the Java Console. https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: It didn't work for me yet. Please any working example made in eclipse for java ee developers in a dynamic web project. The example should have only one applet and one jsp page to run applet. Please soon I am waiting for your kind response...

Comment: Anyone please tell me, how do run applet in a jsp page?

Answer (score 0):

Turn this `code="gui.MainFrame.class"`
To this:
`code="MainFrame.class"` 
And try to make sure the .class file is in your classpath